# Script downloading file from filesonic

Tags: python, scripting

Could somebody please advise me on how I could write a Python script to do these things?

1. Change my IP address to some random proxy address.
2. Download and display the captcha image and show me the prompt where I can write captcha characters.
3. Download the main file.

The script should have one input parameter (the address is similar to one of these):

> http://www.filesonic.com/file/212720521/Ubuntu.11.04.part1.rar
>
> http://www.filesonic.com/file/212720541/Ubuntu.11.04.part2.rar

It would be called twice as follows:

```
python dlsonic.py http://www.filesonic.com/file/212720521/Ubuntu.11.04.part1.rar
python dlsonic.py http://www.filesonic.com/file/212720541/Ubuntu.11.04.part2.rar
```

Comment: Use Python, not bash, as bash isn't made to do this sort of stuff. `wget` can download files, but you don't *change* your IP to that of a proxy server. That's conflicting with their address.

Comment: Thank you, I will modify and retag the question. Could you direct me to the right python libraries (modules)?

Comment: See my answer. The problem with the CAPTCHAs is that once you see it, it changes when you submit. You'll have to use Webkit or some other method to literally "browse" to the website and do all of this. Are you sure you have to go to all this trouble *just* to download Ubuntu ;)

Comment: Advice is one thing, but it really sounds like you're trying to get somebody to just write this all for you.

Comment: @Zaphod42 I'm sorry. I will try to code it and then I will ask. Blender sent me to good direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some basic Python to get you started:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/')
html = response.read() # This is what is read from the file. In your case,
                       # it'll only read the contents of the webpage.
```

To change your IP address, you can use some Linux commands to accomplish this (assuming you're using ethernet here):

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
ifconfig eth0
```

And with Python, you can run these with `os.system()`:

```
import os
os.system('ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up')
os.system('ifconfig eth0')
```

And to handle command line arguments, like `python foo.py bar foo bar bar`:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

As for dealing with the CAPTCHA, that will be tough. Are you sure you can't just do this manually?

Comment: This script should be able to parse HTML and find the link for captcha and the file. When captcha is downloaded I will display it as follows `import Image
import os

im = Image.open("captcha.jpg")
im.show()`

Comment: It should not only change the local IP address but to download the file via some random proxy.

Comment: That's the problem. CAPTCHAs are generated when you create a session. Once you download the image with Python, your session closes, and the CAPTCHA becomes invalid. You'd have to act like a browser and keep the session *open* while you download the image and display it. It'll get nasty...

Comment: Thank you for advising me the language and modules. I will try to implement it and then I will ask more precise question.